# Why is Firestore rejecting the operation?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore action in a react-native project:

```
export const getMessages = (convoId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('messages')
            .where('userConvos', 'array-contains', convoId)
            .orderBy('time')
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                const messages = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    messages.push(doc.data());
                });
                dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_MSGS, payload: messages });
            });
    };
};
```

the two composite indices I've tried in firestore:

[image]

and my database structure is like so:

- Messages (collection)

  - content (field)
  - time (field)
  - userConvos (field)

The problem is when I make this firestore call, I get the

> Error: Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the opereation's execution

But if the error is dismissed, the data is ordered as expected. What's going on and how can this error be eliminated?

Comment: Have you tried doing a google search for that error message? It's been discussed other places.

Comment: yes, all ive found is that its because of the query and requires an index in firestore

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing index. To create it, do the following.

View the android device logs by typing on the terminal:

```
adb logcat
```

If you reproduce the error, then something like the following will appear in the logs:

> 05-16 04:23:20.887  3746  3895 I ReactNativeJS:   nativeErrorMessage:
>   'FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it
>   here:
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/XXXXXXXXX/firestore/indexes?create_composite=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',

Open a browser and paste the link.

Press the `Create Index` button.